# Autohotkey: Send only once when held down

Tags: autohotkey

Here's what I'm trying to do. I want to press the Left shift button down and have it send a double mouse click, then do nothing until the left shift is released, then upon release, send a double click again.

Here's what I have so far:

```
LShift::Click 2
Return

LShift Up::Click 2
Return
```

The problem is, when I hold down the shift key, it continually sends the double click, rather than just sending it once and waiting until it is released to send it again.  Does anyone know an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you have to do

```
LShift::
   Click 2
   keywait, LShift
return

LShift up::
   Click 2
return
```

The keywait prevents it from repeating the key press

Comment: awesome! I knew there had to be a simple answer to this, but couldn't find it through searching.  keywait will be very useful to me. Thanks!

Comment: @Arun Thomas Hi, I'm running into the same situation as OP that I'm trying to send keystrokes to DosBox via AHK. When the key is held down, it would trigger infinity times of the event, even with `Keywait` being used. Any suggestion else?